# le paso null pero se pone automaticamente 1970 , laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Cuando le paso la fecha de egreso o ingreso vacia me devuelve  1970 y no null como corresponderia probe de diferentes maneras pero en todas el null me lo pasa a 1970.

```
  ++$this->numRows;    $usuario= User::updateOrCreate([
       'name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['name']],
       'last_name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['last_name']],
       'telefono' =>$row[ $this ->  nombre['telefono']],
       'fecha_ingreso' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_ingreso']]),
       'status'=>$row[ $this ->  nombre['status']],
       'fecha_egreso'=> \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso']]),
    ]);
```

Comment: Si la fecha es `null` no deberías pasarla como `Date`, sino como cadena vacía para evitar la conversión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

```
$row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso']] == NULL ? NULL : \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso']]) ,
```